# Server Error in '/' Application at entity framework

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework

Server Error in '/' Application at entity framework.

I have added almost all references of MySQL. Every time error was changing

[image]

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
      <providers>
        <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
        <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework, Version=8.0.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
      </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Comment: The error message is self explanatory - _Sections must only appear once_ - you have 2 x `<entityFramework>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is related with a few sections of

> ```
> <entityFramework></entityFramework>
> ```

You have to prepare your config file with just one of it.
You cannot use a few EntityFramework sections into your config file.
EnityFramework section can be in your config only once time and into this one section you have to put your all settings.

So you need something like that:

```
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="..." />
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="..." />
  </parameters>
  <providers>
    <provider ... />
    <provider ... />
    <provider ... />
  </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

just like that.

But the next problem is that you try to use a few db servers at the same time.
It's hard to make this with one DbContext. You would better to use DbContexts for each db.

The best solution of that will be create a for each db connection string into your config file.

More details could you find in
[this place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24996931/entity-framework-6-multiple-defaultconnectionfactory)
if you need use multiple defaultConnectionFactory.
There is some solution of that.